# Content authoring and CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg, files

In my drupal 7 site under Configuration » Content authoring

The following are available:
Filtered HTML
Full Html
Plain text
PHP code

However, under Content authoring » CKEditor

Only the following profiles are available:
Advanced - Filtered HTML
Full - Full HTML

Plain text and the PHP one are missing. Is this normal? Why would this be the case? I am happy to uninstall modules or redo whatever I need to in order for this to be as it should be.

Also, should Filtered HTML and Plain text input formats be editable in the Content authoring section?

Comment: Check permissions.

Comment: Thanks, but I am logged in as an admin though @NikhilM

Comment: admin with uid 1 ?

Comment: uid 1? @NikhilM
I am logged in as the first user created at the time of the site setup, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you see is normal. In any case, having the WYSIWYG editor for Plain text would result in that the output would display the HTML source code. Using the WYSIWYG editor for PHP input format would probably reformat and destroy the PHP code.